# How to prevent _persistentFooterButtons_ to get covered from activated keyboard?

Tags: flutter, dart

When the keyboard is activated, *persistentFooterButtons* are covered.

```
...
persistentFooterButtons: <Widget>[
    ButtonBar(
    children: [
      IconButton(
      iconSize: 15,
      onPressed: () {},
      icon: Icon(Icons.east, color: Colors.green),
    ),
    IconButton(
    iconSize: 15,
    onPressed: () {},
    icon: Icon(Icons.api, color: Colors.blue),
   ),],),],
  ); //Scaffold
```

When the keyboard is activated, the icons should be displayed above the keyboard.

Answer (score -1):

write in floatingActionButton

for example :

```
  floatingActionButton: Column(
    children: [
      Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(child: Container()),
          FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: _incrementCounter,
            tooltip: 'Increment',
            child: Icon(Icons.add),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      Container(
        height: 1, color: Colors.grey , margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10 , left: 30),
      ),
      Container(
        child:     ButtonBar(
          children: [
            IconButton(
              iconSize: 15,
              onPressed: () {},
              icon: Icon(Icons.extension, color: Colors.green),
            ),
            IconButton(
              iconSize: 15,
              onPressed: () {},
              icon: Icon(Icons.ac_unit, color: Colors.blue),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      )
    ],
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
  ), //
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I find the persistentFooterButtons a lot more elegant. But it looks like there is no way to keep it above the keyboard without using a hack.